# I am not able to install any npm packages in VS code, getting below error,is there any issues in VS code latest version which is released in FEB 2021?

Tags: visual-studio-code

npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: VS code does not have anything to do with `npm`. `npm` is part of Nodejs.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. i can't update to latest because the codebase is quite old. Still looking for solution :(

did you find any solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this terminal command?

npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: Yes, I tried npm install npm@latest -g this also but getting same error

Comment: https://nodejs.yocker.com/4811/npm-err-codice-unable_to_get_issuer_cert_locally.html

Comment: check this link if you haven't done this before .. but i think so .. sorry i cant suggest further .. good luck

Comment: the link doesn't work anymore...